# Cannot use Array.prototype.some/every as expression

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Let's suppose I've an array `myArray` and a button.

```
<button>Click</button>
```

And I wanna use Array.prototype.some/every to disable the button, using ng-disabled directive. For example:

```
<button ng-disabled="myArray.some(x => x == 1)">Click</button>
```

This throws `Token '>' not a primary expression at column  of the expression`.

Why that happens? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes: you're using an arrow function inside an angularJS expression, and Angular expressions don't support that. Call a function of your scope/controller, and put the JavaScript code there.

Comment: @JBNizet Exactly, I did call a function from my controller... but I just want to understand... Angular expressions don't support arrow functions... is there a reason for this?

Comment: Well, for one, when AngularJS expressions were designed, arrow functions didn't exist. Another reason is that it makes things much more complex for a negative gain, since it's bad practice to put too much logic in the view.

Comment: If you want to run more complex JavaScript code, you should make it a controller method and call the method from your view. Read [AngularJS Developer Guide - AngularJS Ecpressions vs JS Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions).

Comment: Thanks, @georgeawg, that does make sense. `You cannot declare functions in an AngularJS expression, even inside ng-init directive.`

Comment: Also be aware that controller methods inside the `ng-disabled` directive are invoked two or more times each digest cycle. It is better to create a `disabled` state in the model than compute it repeditively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [AngularJS Developer Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#angularjs-expressions-vs-javascript-expressions) says, one cannot declare functions inside AngularJS expressions.

> **No Function Declarations:** You cannot declare functions in an AngularJS expression, even inside ng-init directive.